# Urllib2: get content of html page

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I need to parse information from some urls:

```
http://novosibirsk.baza.drom.ru/personal/actual/bulletins
http://drom.ru
http://novosibirsk.baza.drom.ru
http://moscow.drom.ru/volvo/xc70/21914186.html
http://novosibirsk.baza.drom.ru/personal/actual/bulletins
http://novosibirsk.baza.drom.ru/kolpaki-reno-r15-kubera-30227564.html
```

And I try parse from this some information

```
if 'drom.ru' in url:
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

But it returns to me empty pages.
Where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: can you access site from browser? (if no, goto step 4)

Step 2: can you access site from command-line such as wget, curl, etc.? (if no, goto step 4)

Step 3: Check for proxy issues/try a different library like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Step 4: Get it working in the browser/command-line first, then go back to step 1

Answer (score -1):

Using `requests` will make it more easier. If you dont have `requests` module installed, try to install it by `pip install requests`

```
import requests

if 'drom.ru' in url:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') # lxml works faster than html.parser
```